# XmlSerializer does not show changes into an existing instance

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have googled a lot and its still not working, all my int and Strings etc don't change their valaues

My code for de-/serialization:

```
public void serialize()
{
   XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Stundenplan));
   TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"daten.xml");
   xs.Serialize(writer, this);
   writer.Close();
}  //seems to work since the xml file looks good

public void deserialization()
{
   XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Stundenplan));
   TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"daten.xml");
   Stundenplan stu;
   stu = (Stundenplan)xs.Deserialize(reader);
}  // don't see any change
```

Here are my classes involved in the serialization, without all the voids:

```
public class Stundenplan
{
    public Fach[] faecher = new Fach[100];
    public int fachnr = 0;
```

.......(many voids)
    }

```
public class Fach
{
    public String name;
    public bool[] stunden = new bool[8];
    public Hausaufgabe[] hausaufgaben = new Hausaufgabe[10000];
    public int hausaufgabennr = 0;
    public String lehrer;
```

....(also a few voids)
    }

```
public class Hausaufgabe
{
    public DateTime datum;
    public String beschreibung;
    public bool gemacht;

    public Hausaufgabe()
    {
    }
}
```

What is missing/wrong??

Comment: can you post the content of daten.xml?

Comment: what is your problem? You deserialize into a local variable. where should you see a change?

Comment: To ensure you are letting go of the daten.xml file, you should wrap the stream reader and stream writer in a using instead of just calling close. This ensures garbage collection will free the resources used on next run. Dispose also calls close for you.

Comment: In addition to the answer given (which is correct) note that very few serializers allow you to deserialize into an existing instance. Some do, but as the exception.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in the following line:

```
stu = (Stundenplan)xs.Deserialize(reader);
```

You're deserializing the value into a different instance (`stu` instead of `this`) which you throw away at the end of the method. You should rewrite the `deserialization()` method like this:

```
public static Stundenplan deserialization()
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Stundenplan));
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"daten.xml");
    return (Stundenplan)xs.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Of course you should then also change the way you are calling it:

```
Stundenplan sp = Stundenplan.deserialization();
```

instead of

```
Stundenplan sp = new Stundenplan();
sp.deserialization();
```

Comment: I have one more question, when i implement try catch, what sould i return??